# "It is ok" synonym expression

Tags: expressions, synonyms, sentence-usage

I have used the expression "It is ok." when the character is calming down herself, so she would stop from getting annoyed or angry. But I have used it a lot, that's why I want another synonym that can be used in the same way I use "It is ok."

An example sentence: "It is ok. She is just trying to provoke me."

I have searched the web and found: **all right** and **fine**. Can those two fit the usage I want with adding the (It is) part?

Comment: What character? What context? Is the same thing always happening when the expression is used? It's possible there could be a wide range of things you could say instead—depending on what this is referring to. I don't think you actually want either of those synonyms. They seem too contrived. (Like something you'd look up in a thesaurus for variety.) What you want is different expressions, like *calm down*, *take a breath*, *easy does it*, or *don't worry*.

Comment: It is an informal story. I was intending a character in it. Yes, I thought that too. The expressions you suggest are pretty suitable to what I need. Thanks. But you said that there are many more, is there a reference I can go to to get those many?

Comment: No, not that I can think of. I'm not sure how many more there could be in this case (given that what I suggested are all along the lines of what you're looking for), but I'm sure at least a few more that didn't occur to me.

Comment: That's fine; they will do the job. Thank you again. I thought of _relax_ as an addition to the collection.